# Alocar o usúario para definir o tamanho do vetor

Tags: c++

Olá, estou resolvendo um ex. básico de c++ onde pede para o fazer uma função que receba como parâmetro um vetor de n° reais e que leia do teclado n n° reais, guarde-os no vetor e calcule a sua média. 
a função deve retornar a média.

Enfim, meu problema é, como fazer o usuário alocar o tamanho do vetor, SEM UTILIZAR memória dinâmica.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float VetorCalculaMedia(int n, float vet[])
{

    float soma = 0;
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       cout << " Type the array elements: " << endl;
       cin >> vet[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
           soma += vet[i];
    }
    return soma/n;
}
int main ()
{

    int n;
    cout << "type the array size: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    float vet[n];
    **cout << "The media is: " << VetorCalculaMedia(n, vet[n]) << endl;**
    return 0;
}
```

na linha em negrito o erro é 'Cannot convert float to float*'

Comment: Quando você faz `vet[n]` está se referindo a um elemento do vetor, no caso o (n+1)-ésimo elemento já que o índice parte de zero. Sua função espera receber um vetor e não um elemnto do vetor. Use: `cout << "The media is: " << VetorCalculaMedia(n, vet) << endl;`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!